# Connecting 3 PCs in a LAN

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, ping, vlan

I'm running on GNS3 and in my topology I've connected 3 PCs. PC1 is connected to PC2 via eth0 and PC3 is connected to PC2 via eth1.

I can only ping between PC1 and PC2. I cannot ping between PC2 and PC3. Should the ping be successfully since it's connected via a different ethernet? I ran
        ifconfig eth1 up
to be sure but it's not successful. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Comment: i need more info.

Comment: Okay so on PC1 eth0 I connected it to PC2 on it's eth0. On PC3 eth1 I connected it to PC2 on it's eth1. I can ping from PC2 to PC3 but I cannot ping from PC2 to PC3.

    [PC1(eth0)] <-> [(eth0)PC2(eth1)] <-> [(eth1)PC3]

Comment: ok. did you make a bridge between pc2 eth0 and pc2 eth1 ?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I want to jump in there and get my hands dirty but this seems like a pretty trivial problem (done in a simulator no less)... and I don't want to deprive anyone of a learning experience.

Comment: Also, what are the assigned IP addresses & netmasks?

Comment: this looks like a routing problem.

Comment: Unless it's a homework assignment, it would probably be best to just say, "You don't want to do it like that."

Comment: Ethernet switches are cheap and let PC1 talk with PC3 even if PC2 is off or absent.

Comment: Yes I made a bridge between pc2 eth0 and pc2 eth1.
And yes, it is a lab assignment I'm working on.

Comment: @NathanialMeek If you are trying to get  somebodys question closed and deprive them of help, then at least do be more honest about what you are trying to do. Depriving somebody of help for a problem wherever the problem is from, is often not really a good way to help them.  And if  on the odd occasion where you can answer, all you can ever do is solve somebodys problem without showing them how to solve it themselves, then you'll always be depriving people of a learning experience in every answer you give.

Comment: @barlop I wasn't trying to get a persons question closed at all. I was merely looking for more information to determine whether or not I wanted to assist in the matter. I, generally, follow problems through in explicit detail. If the roles were reversed and I was in his situation, a person working through the problem as I typically would, would just about starve me of any chance of learning it myself. I learn hands on and make it a point to figure things out by myself unless otherwise impossible. Regardless, I meant no offense.